# Display custom fields in WordPress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

How do I call out several fields from current post within a widget? I've already adjusted my functions.php to allow PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php global $wp_query;
if(is_object($wp_query->queried_object) && $wp_query->queried_object->ID)
{
    echo get_post_meta($wp_query->queried_object->ID, 'customfieldname', true);
}
?>
```